# passing and retrieving variables in cakephp from javascript using GET METHOD

Tags: javascript, cakephp, post, get

i know how to construct url parameters in javascript and i know how to extract it if im going to pass it to a php file.

However, here's the scenario, i am going to pass variables from javascript to a function. I have 2 textboxes and i can already get the values of these textboxes and store it to javascript variables:

```
var fname;
name = document.getElementById('fname');
var lname;
lname=document.getElementById('name');
```

now im stucked up on how i am going to construct it in a way that cakephp post method will be able to understand it. is it just the same with php like the code below?

```
var vars = "fname="+fname+"&lname="+lname;
```

here's my code:

```
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
            xmlVariable = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else{
            xmlVariable = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft","XMLHTTP");
        }

xmlVariable.open("POST","save",true);
xmlVariable.send(vars);
```

"save" is actually a function in my cakephp where i wanna process the saving of "fname" and "lname" variables.

i need to do it in cakephp. Would there be any way?

Answer (score 1):

Try with **Params** or **data**

Params variable is used to provide access to information about the current request.

```
public function save()
    {
        this->params['form']['lname'];
        this->params['form']['fname'];
    }
```

**OR**

Used to handle POST data sent from the FormHelper forms to the controller.

```
 public function save()
        {
            this->data['lname'];
            this->data['fname'];
        }
```

Comment: If using cake2.0+ just add `$this->request->params` and `$this->request->data`